# Building Recognition in Vuforia&Unity

Tags: vuforia

I would like to make a mobile application so that when a user points at a building it will render various information. My problem is that I really don't know if this can be done. I mean the only way is to take an image of the building and upload it as an image target in unity. But what if the image will change over time (vegetation?) or the user points the camera from a different perspective than the one I used?
Is there a way to make this so that the problem mentioned above won't be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in several ways (or even combine them together):

- Write a mechanism that will be able to download updated Vuforia datasets from a server into your app in runtime. This way, you can update the building images when you wish, and ensure it will be detected if something changes
- Make sure you take enough pictures of the building from enough perspectives. You can use many images of the building in a single Vuforia dataset
- Try to find a partial sections or sections of the building that is very likely to remain unchanged.